# Why we need to substract one period when calculating Present Value?

Tags: interest-rate, calculation

The question is:
Grandparents are funding a newborn’s future university tuition costs, estimated at $50,000/year for four years, with the first payment due as a lump sum in 18 years. Assuming a 6% effective annual rate, the required deposit today is closest to?

The solution is: 
[image]

I don't understand why we are using 17 Years but not 18 years as it was asked in the task?

Comment: Post a transcript of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, it seems to imply that since

> "the first payment due as a lump sum in 18 years"

The payment is due on day 1 (the beginning) of the 18th year. Which is why you calculate the PV of the ordinary annuity at year 17. Which is why $173,255.28 is the **present value** of 4 payments of $50,000 each.

The PV at the end of year 17 can also be calculated as:
(50,000/(1+0.06)^1) + (50,000/(1+0.06)^2) + (50,000/(1+0.06)^3) + (50,000/(1+0.06)^4) = **$173,255.28**

Perhaps that's a bit more intuitive? (Discounting the cash flows by the time period they occur after the **end** of year 17, for the subsequent 4 years)

Then since **$173,255.28** is the PV at year 17, the deposit needed today to ensure that 
the grandparents have $173,255.28 at the end of year 17 is (173,255.28/(1+0.06)^17) as stated in the solution.